# Intern Async Test

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, intern

I am trying to get an async intern test working using a separate module to do the request call. I am having an issue returning true once the test is done because I always get a timeout error, even though the request is successful, and the test runs to completion. After the test runs it just sits on the last page and times out. login_test.js is the test file, companyCreate is the request calling file that exists in an external module. I'm not quite sure what is happening to my test return call if I pass it into deferred.callback().

```
// login_test.js
define([
'intern!object',
'pages/loginpage',
'runtime/testConfig',
'intern/dojo/node!nconf',
'helpers/companyCreate',
'locators/loginpage',
'locators/companyselectionpage'

], function(registerSuite, LoginPage, conf, nconf, Company) {

var tests = {

    name: 'Login test',

    'Test': function() {

        /* make a call to create a company
        * param1: test function to run after we get response with login details
        * param2: intern object so we can make it async
        */
        Company.createCompany(function(response, testObj) {

            testObj.timeout = 120000; //The default timeout is 30 seconds. Not enough

            var region = nconf.get("region"); //Getting command line region value
            var regionData = conf.get(region); //Fetching  config data based on region
            var loginId = regionData.LOGIN;
            var password = regionData.PASSWORD;

            var loginPage = new LoginPage(testObj.remote, regionData.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

            var companySelectionPage = loginPage
                .load(regionData.BASE_URL)
                .loginIn(loginId, password);
            var homePage = companySelectionPage
                .doesCurrentURLContain('/companysel')
                .isTitlePresent()
                .selectCompany(CompanySelectionLocators.data);
            return homePage
                .doesCurrentURLContain('/homepage')
                .getAccumulatedState();
        }, this);
    }
};

registerSuite(tests);
});
```

>

```
// companyCreate.js
define(function(require) {
var request = require('intern/dojo/request');

var Company = {

    createCompany: function(callbackArg, testObj) {
        // tell intern this is async
        var deferred = testObj.async(120000);

        // make post
        request.post('https://internal.com/createcompany', {
            query: {
                version: ".0.1",
                special: "true"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                userName: "Test",
                password: "pass",
                userEmail: "email@hi.com"
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json"
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            // success, tell intern async is done, return test function to run and pass it the response
            console.log(response);
            return deferred.callback(callbackArg(response, testObj));
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }, function(evt) {
            //console.log(evt);
        });
    }
};

return Company;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution is below.  I had no need for this.async.  comapnyCreate.js returns the response and promise from the request. login_test.js runs the test after the promise is fulfilled.  (still needs some error handling logic)

```
// login_test.js
define([
    'intern!object',
    'pages/loginpage',
    'runtime/testConfig',
    'intern/dojo/node!nconf',
    'helpers/companyCreate',
    'locators/loginpage',
    'locators/companyselectionpage'

], function(registerSuite, LoginPage, conf, nconf, Company) {

var tests = {

    name: 'Login test',

    'Test': function() {

        this.timeout = 60000;
        var remote = this.remote;

        return Company.createCompany().then(function(response) {

            var region = nconf.get("region"); //Getting command line region value
            var regionData = conf.get(region); //Fetching  config data based on region
            var loginId = regionData.LOGIN;
            var password = regionData.PASSWORD;

            var loginPage = new LoginPage(remote, regionData.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

            var companySelectionPage = loginPage
                .load(regionData.BASE_URL)
                .loginIn(loginId, password);
            var homePage = companySelectionPage
                .doesCurrentURLContain('/companysel')
                .isTitlePresent()
                .selectCompany(CompanySelectionLocators.data);
            return homePage
                .doesCurrentURLContain('/homepage')
                .getAccumulatedState();
        });
    }
};

registerSuite(tests);
});
```

> 

```
// companyCreate.js
define(function(require) {
var request = require('intern/dojo/request');

var Company = {

    createCompany: function() {
        // make post
        return request.post('https://internal.com/createcompany', {
            query: {
                version: ".0.1",
                special: "true"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                userName: "Test",
                password: "pass",
                userEmail: "email@hi.com"
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json"
            }
        });
    }
};

return Company;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`deferred.callback` is intended to be used to wrap another callback that is executed at another time. It doesn’t resolve the underlying Promise, it returns a new function that, when invoked, resolves the Promise if the passed in callback function doesn’t throw an error. For example:

```js
'Test': function () {
  var dfd = this.async();

  // this use of `dfd.callback`…
  fs.readFile('foo.txt', dfd.callback(function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    assert.strictEqual(data, 'hello, world');
  }));

  // …is equivalent to this without it:
  fs.readFile('foo.txt', function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      dfd.reject(error);
      return;
    }

    try {
      assert.strictEqual(data, 'hello, world');
    }
    catch (error) {
      dfd.reject(error);
      return;
    }

    dfd.resolve();
  }));
}
```

You should be using `deferred.resolve`, which resolves the promise to the value passed as the first argument. See the [async tests documentation](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#async-tests) for more detailed information on each of these functions.